# New Android UI color palette docs, don't understand some colors names (A100, A200...)

Tags: android, color, standards

About color palette:

[Android UI Color Palette](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-ui-color-palette)

[image: Palette]

What are the color starting with 'A' (A100, A200)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**A** stands for **Accent**.  They are colors that *accent* the primary colors.  Here's what Google says:

### [UI Color Application](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-ui-color-application)

---

> **Choose your palette**
>
> Limit your choice of colors by choosing three color hues in the primary and one accent color in the secondary palette. The accent color may or may not need fall back options.

[image]

> **Accent color**
>
> The vibrant accent colors are used for your primary action buttons as well as components such as switchers or sliders. Left aligned section icons or section titles can also take on the accent color.

[image]

Comment: @Downvoter - Care to explain why my answer deserves a downvote? Is there something I can improve?

Comment: I upvoted your answer, thanks. Just confused about the "accent" meaning.

Comment: @Seraphim'shost - I updated the answer for you to make things clearer.